# How to force a bean to dispose after Spring AMQP beans

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have a Spring Boot application and I'm using Spring AMQP. I need to implement my own custom logic on `ApplicationContext` closing event so I implemented `DisposableBean` in my bean, like this:

```
public class ShutdownHandler implements DisposableBean {

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
       // I need access message listener containers here
    }  
}
```

The problem is that when I run my code, all the AMQP beans have been already shut down and I receive the following exception:

```
The ApplicationContext is closed and the ConnectionFactory can no longer create connections.
```

Mainly, I need to move messages from some queues to others, in order to resume processing when my application starts again. 
I found that the issue is due to `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` having phase set with Integer.MAX_VALUE so it will be disposed as one of the first application context beans. 
What I tried (without success):

1. `@DependsOn("listenerContainer")` annotation
2. Implementing `SmartLifecycle` and setting phase Integer.MAX_VALUE

Do you know other ways to force the order during application context shutdown phase and have access to Spring AMQP beans?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't interact with other beans during context destruction.

The connection factory (which is where you are getting the error is in phase `Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1000`, which means it's one of the last beans to be `stopped()` (`phase` has no relevance for bean destruction order).

Instead of implementing `DisposableBean`, implement `SmartLifecycle` instead. Put your bean in a phase larger than the connection factory.

You can also change the phase of the listener container if needed.

So, your second option should have worked as long as your bean's phase is larger than the connection factory - that message is only emitted after the factory has stopped (which is in a very early phase - so stopped very late).

You can observe the bean stopping order by turning on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework`. If you still can't figure out what's wrong, post the DEBUG log someplace and show your listener and factory configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution, through implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>`. That event is fired at the very beginning of application context closing and before the disposal of beans and it's what I needed.